# java not recognizing second classpath

Tags: java

This is my first time with java, so take it easy on me.

I have a project directory that looks like this:

```
src
|-- main
|    |-- Game.java
|    |-- Game.class
|-- resources
|    |--lanterna
|         |-- java
|              |--(classes I want to import)
```

So my Game.java file has some imports like this:

```java
import com.googlecode.lanterna.terminal.Terminal;  // This is inside of src/resources/lanterna/java
```

I compile it using the command:
`javac src/main/Game.java -cp src/resources/lanterna/java`

And I try to run it by creating an array of classpaths and inputting that as the classpath argument.

```sh
CLASSPATH=(src/main src/resources/lanterna/java)
java Game -cp ${CLASSPATH}
```

But is get this error:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class Game
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/googlecode/lanterna/screen/Screen
```

Comment: How are those classes kept under lanterna/java?

Comment: Java source files should be under `main`, not `resources`.

Answer (score 0):

`CLASSPATH` must be colon-separated:

```
CLASSPATH=src/main:src/resources/lanterna/java
```

Comment: Colon [:] on *nix (and Mac), semicolon [;] on Windows, including if you're using Cygwin.

Comment: @dan.mwasuser2321368 Judging by the file path in the OP's example (with forward slashes), they are on Unix/Mac.